# How to create a symlink to open a directory in Terminal on Mac osx?

Tags: macos, bash, unix, symlink

There are certain folders I am cd'ing into all day long...for instance, "dev" which is in my Documents folder.

I had this bright idea to set up symlinks so I could simply type "dev" and Terminal would cd into that directory.  This doesn't seem to work though.  My two attempts are below.

Anyone know how to do this or is there a better way?

```
ln -s /Users/kelly/Documents/Dev/ dev
ln -s 'cd /Users/kelly/Documents/Dev/' dev

$ dev
bash: dev: command not found
```

Comment: Just as an interesting note, `zsh` provides an option `AUTO_CD` where a "command" like `dev` is treated as an implicit `cd dev` if the command cannot be executed. Coupled with `CDPATH`, this would provide the feature you are looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a symlink you can use

```
ln -s your/dev/directory/ dev
```

but you can only use it in the directory you created it in and in the form of `cd dev`.

If you just want to type `dev` at any point, use an alias:

```
alias dev="cd your/dev/direcrory/"
```

(this should then be in your `~/.bashrc`)

Comment: Thanks!  I accepted this one because you explained why my idea wouldn't work and then offered an alternative.

Comment: @Kelly I learned a lot of shortcuts including aliases (and some of them really handy) by looking through [.dotfiles](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles) repos on github. That one is OSX centric but my understanding is most of it would work on any Unix system and there are equally good .dotfiles repos for Linux

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `alias` for dev. Add to your ${HOME}/.bashrc

```
 alias dev='cd /Users/kelly/Documents/Dev/'
```

and bash correctly parses `~` in an alias:

```
 alias dev='cd ~/Documents/Dev/'
```

Using an alias eliminates the need for the symbolic link at all.

Comment: Alias should contain a `=` and `~Documents/` refers to the home directory of the user `Documents` and not the folder `Documents` in the user's home folder!

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `cd dev` in your case, but it might be better for you to use [bash aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28Unix_shell%29)...

Write in your `$HOME/.bash_aliases` file:

```
alias dev='cd /Users/kelly/Documents/Dev/'
```

after opening a new terminal executing `dev` will give you, what you want...

Answer (score 1):

In your $HOME/.bashrc, declare an array which maps directories to aliases.

```
declare -A __diraliasmap=(
  [dev]="/Users/kelly/Documents/Dev"
  [other]="/Users/kelly/Documents"
)
```

Also define a command_not_found_handle function.  If defined, this function will be run by bash when a command is not found.  In the function, check whether the command which failed is listed as an alias for a directory and, if so, cd to the associated directory.

```
command_not_found_handle()
{
  if [[ ${__diraliasmap[$1]+set} = set ]]; then
    builtin cd "${__diraliasmap[$1]}"
  else
    false
  fi
}
```